# Hardcoded values in NG-OPTIONS with dynamic values from NG-REPEAT

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Let's say we have this data and it's being returned by an API

```
$scope.arrayOfStudentObjects = [
    { name : 'Ashley', gender : 'female' },
    { name : 'Tom', gender : 'male' },
    { name : 'Scott', gender : 'male' }
];
```

Then the values that we put in < select > are in a scope

```
$scope.gender = [ { type : 'male' }, { type : 'female' } ];
```

Now we want to display the values and correctly set the selection for the gender in the select dropdown

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in arrayOfStudentObjects track by $index">
    <select ng-model="student.gender" ng-options="sex.type for sex in gender"></select>
</tr>
```

However, I'm not sure why it's not displaying/selecting the proper gender for that student. Please see Plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/o0Wt2Qg8BFXmeeMqFBIE?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `<select...>` to

```
 <select ng-model="student.gender" ng-options="sex.type as sex.type for sex in gender"></select>
```

otherwise the value it compares to is the full object.

forked plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/azBhpIEUkybXmQWliMOR?p=preview